# Calculate the 2 columns from table and insert the result as other column in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a table with some columns like orderID,custId,unitprice,Quantity.Now I want to add the other column as Totalprice by multiplying quantity*unitprice.

I have altered the table  by adding the totalprice column to the existing table
**alter table orders add totalprice int**
and then I have tried with insert query
**insert into orders (totalprice) select quantity*unitprice from orders**
And also I have tried with creating some temp table also but the temp table would not used furtherly.

Please let me know how to put this query in order to insert a column.

**Totalprice=quantity*unitprice**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to `INSERT` any record once the column is added. What you need is to `UPDATE` the records.

```
UPDATE Orders SET TotalPrice = Quantity * UnitPrice
```

Alternatively, you could take a look at [computed columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx). This would save you the trouble of making sure your `Total` column is up to date with both the `Quantity` and `UnitPrice` columns.

```
ALTER TABLE Orders ADD TotalPrice AS Quantity * UnitPrice
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make this total price column a computed column. as follows ....

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName 
ADD  totalprice AS (quantity*unitprice)
GO
```

Comment: Thank you M.Ali. Yes it is Correct.